# How to Use background service in android

Tags: android, android-service

I am going to use background services in my application, i am using some code but its no working.

```
  public class MyService extends Service {


   String tag="TestService";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
   Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
     }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
   super.onStart(intent, startId);  
   Log.i(tag, "Service started...");
      }
    @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   return null;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `onStart()` is deprecated, use `onStartCommand()` instead.

How do you start your service? You should probably start it from your activity, using:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Also, in services, use:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

instead of:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```